# I want to add a new label to a form using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, label, vb.net-2010

The code that I am using below does not work, I am fairly experienced with vb.net and have never run into this issue before, the label simply doesn't appear when the form loads (the code is inside the Load event handler procedure).

```
Dim currentUserLabel As New Label 
    With {.Text = "Logged in as: " + firstName + " " + _ lastName, 
    .Location = New Point(5, 3), .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 
    18, FontStyle.Bold)}
MenuTab.Controls.Add(currentUserLabel)
currentUserLabel.AutoSize = True
currentUserLabel.BringToFront()
MenuTab.Refresh()
```

Comment: ditto - add a label in the designer where you want it to go and see what the location is, then use that

Comment: There used to just be a label on the tab, but its text wouldn't change even when I refreshed it or invalidated it. So I have decided to try making a new one every time instead, the old label was definitely at (5, 3)

Comment: its not supposed to change when the form/control is invalidated or refreshed, just when the text property changes.  pretty much overkill to create a new control when the Text property changes.  Be sure to properly dispose of the old control(s): you build them, you burn them.

Comment: It's still not working, everything I have tried doesn't work, could someone give me an example of the code that they would use to change the text of a label?

Comment: `FormName.LabelName.Text = "Text To Show"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally sorted it, I invalidated the label when the form loaded, then created an event method which handles the invalidation of the label. I used the code that I had already been trying in this method and it worked. No idea why it wouldn't just load the label text when the form loaded :P. VB is stupid sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add controls to the TabControl, just it's pages.

```
 Dim currentUserLabel As New Label With {.Text = "Logged in as: " + firstName + " " + _ lastName,
 .Location = New Point(5, 3), .Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, FontStyle.Bold)}
 MenuTab.TabPages(0).Controls.Add(currentUserLabel)
 currentUserLabel.AutoSize = True
```

Comment: MenuTab IS a tab page not a tab control

Comment: Then I cannot recreate the problem.